# Как считать данные из Ajax-запроса в Serlvet?

Tags: java, ajax, servlet

Отправляю Ajax запрос на Сервлет. Вопрос: Как на сервлете считать данные из этого запроса и засунуть, допустим, значение переменной Group в String(java)?

```
function () {
    var group = $("#group").val();
    var request = {};
    request.group = group;

    $.ajax({ ///////////////////////
        type: "POST",
        url: "/first",
        dataType: "json",
        data: request,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.key);
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/first";
            window.open(url);
        }
    }); ////////////////
}
```

Comment: ajax надо посылать на контроллер, на контроллере принимать обект который описывает json

Comment: Обычным образом. String group = request.getParameter("group"). ajax запрос не отличим от обычного запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax запрос

```
$.ajax({
        url:"/send",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        accepts: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        data : {"id":1, "name":"Test"}
        ...
});
```

Обект Java

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //getter setter
}
```

Контроллер

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
     @RequestMapping(value="/send", method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public void send(@RequestBody User User){
     }
}
```